# In Slick 2.x/3.x, where should I place extra Static methods associated with a Table?

Tags: playframework, slick, slick-2.0, typesafe, slick-3.0

In the [upgrade guide](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html) of Slick 3.0, I found contents like this:

> In Slick 1.0 it was common practice to place extra static methods
>   associated with a table into that table’s object. You can do the same
>   in 2.0 with a custom TableQuery object:

```
object suppliers extends TableQuery(new Suppliers(_)) {
  // put extra methods here, e.g.:
  val findByID = this.findBy(_.id)
}
```

Does this mean putting static methods into the table's object is not a common practice or not recommended in Slick 2.x/3.x? (By the way, the syntax of `object suppliers extends TableQuery(new Suppliers(_))` looks a bit weird.)

If it is not, what is the preferred way to put the static methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create objects from Slick >= 2.0's table classes anymore. The tag it tags can only be generated by Slick. Extend TableQuery instead, so `object suppliers extends TableQuery(new Suppliers(_))` is the place.